# Close socket and select()

Tags: unix, sockets

So I need to close a particular connection, but the problem is another thread is, at the same time, doing a select() which has the socket as one of the file descriptors it's watching.

Will the select() terminate gracefully, or will anything bad happen?

Comment: Dup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543541/what-does-select2-do-if-you-close2-a-file-descriptor-in-a-separate-thread and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458558/select-on-udp-socket-doesnt-end-when-socket-is-closed-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but nothing bad should happen if you close the socket **after** the `select()` started. `select()` will return an error if you pass **already** closed socket to it at the beggining (see [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)).

Also, if you use `select()` to wait for data to read it may report this closed socket as ready for read (because read won't block on closed socket).

You may write a simple program and actually check what will happen on your system.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer I got to nearly the same question:

[Wake up thread blocked on accept() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486335/wake-up-thread-blocked-on-accept-call)

Short answer: have your select call wait on two file handles: the socket and the read-side of the pipe.