# socket select() creates a thread and close() doesn't end thread

Tags: c++, sockets, cygwin

When I do a select on a socket it creates a thread. When I close the socket it does not release the thread.

I am running the code in cygwin. At the first pause I attach gdb and there are three threads (not sure why three). I quit gdb and continue the program which opens does the following: open socket, bind, select, close. I then hit the second pause and then attach gdb and there are now four threads. I have even added a shutdown. I am sure that I am missing something simple but I can't seem to find it.

Here is the code.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <shlobj.h>

using namespace std;

void mySleep(int miliSeconds)
{
    usleep(miliSeconds * 1000);
}

void mySleep(int miliSeconds)
{
//    Sleep(miliSeconds);
    usleep(miliSeconds * 1000);
}


void myPause()
{
    cout << "Paused, hit enter to continue..."<< endl;

    getchar();
}


int main()
{
    myPause();
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;

    client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_addr.sin_port = htons(10000);
    client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    struct hostent* server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof (serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, (char *) server->h_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(10000);

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error opening socket" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    int retCode;
    socklen_t sockAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

    retCode = bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, sockAddrLen);
    if (retCode < 0)
    {
        cout << "Unable to bind" << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set socks;

    FD_ZERO(&socks);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &socks);

    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    retCode = select(sockfd + 1, &socks, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (retCode < 0)
    {
        cout << "Unable to select" << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    retCode = shutdown(sockfd, 2);  // 2 = stop both reception and transmission
    if (retCode < 0)
    {
        cout << "Unable to shutdown" << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    retCode = close(sockfd);
    if (retCode < 0)
    {
        cout << "Unable to close" << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    sockfd = -1;

    mySleep(5000);
    myPause();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is how cygwin implements `select()`? If so, then there's no need to worry too much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select on UDP socket doesn't end when socket is closed - what am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458558/select-on-udp-socket-doesnt-end-when-socket-is-closed-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: Try to add the reusable option to the socket so it will be opened even if it havn't timeout.

Comment: `cout << "Unable to bind" << endl` in C you cannot bitshift strings. `using namespace std;` and C has no namespaces, either. Maybe you are using C++ ? BTW C has no threads (and in your code I cannot see any lines referring to thread libraries)

Comment: @wildplasser but cygwin implements select using threads.

Comment: I see. So they just have one thread polling the file descriptors and spinning. I thought windows had some `WaitForMultipleEventsAndCallMeBackWhenYouAreDone( WM_ASAP_PLEASE)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Closing a UDP socket simply doesn't cause a select on that socket to end. I'm unclear why, but this is expected behavior. See [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458558/select-on-udp-socket-doesnt-end-when-socket-is-closed-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait I think this is one of the reasons.

Comment: @cerkiewny - not relevant. The problem isn't closing the socket, the problem is that an open select on said socket doesn't release when the socket is closed.

Comment: Thank you all. I would expect after a few minutes the thread would disappear but it doesn't. If I call select() repeatedly it doesn't create more threads so I guess I should be happy and move on. Very unsettling. Again thanks.